# Is there a combination of columns in sys.dm_exec_sessions that is unique per the server?

Tags: sql-server, dmv, session

In SQL Server, each session has its own spid. Spids are unique at any given notice, but spids, like process and thread identifiers in the OS are recycled.

However [sys.dm_exec_sessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) has other columns with session metadata. Is there a combination of columns that is guaranteed to be unique for a server instance?

Comment: Are you talking about being able to tell two spids apart if you are taking snapshots of sys.dm_exec_sessions over time?

Comment: I don't think there are any combination of columns that can guarantee uniqueness for the lifetime of the server. For example, when the clocks get set back an hour (for a server in a time zone that practices daylight savings) and 2 sessions start exactly an hour apart and get the same session ID, that would not be unique.

Comment: @AaronBertrand well I'm trying to see if a spid still exists.

Comment: @RobertLDavis I'm really ok with edge case false positives for my purposes.

Comment: In that case, you are probably okay with those columns. I only called it out because you asked for a guarantee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions belong to connections (1:M) and connections have unique GUID identifier, see [`sys.dm_exec_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx):

> `connection_id` **uniqueidentifier** Identifies each connection uniquely. Is
>   not nullable.

Whenever you capture sys.dm_exec_sessions, join with sys.dm_exec_connections and capture the connection_id too.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate a spid with its start time via the login_time column. Other than a spid being recycled at a rate faster than the resolution of login_time, this is unique per server instance.